# Linux: /proc/stat info is not consistent with top command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Here's the output (first line) of `cat /proc/stat`:

```
$ cat /proc/stat
cpu  1089754000 1806405811 36616 32667836 1477 0 11090 12536 0 0
```

whereas at the same time, if I run `top` command, this is what it shows:

```
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.1 sy,  6.3 ni, 93.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Which obvious is not consistent between each other (e.g., user=1089754000 and nice=1806405811 is much higher than idle=32667836 in /proc/stat whereas its reversed in `top` command)

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers in `/proc/stat` are totals from the time the system was booted. The values in `top` reflect the current utilization, in other words the rate of change of the stat values.

Put another way, the stat values are like the mileage on a car, compared to the speed of the car.

Comment: any idea where does top gets all infos regarding cpu & load balance? Since new relic could still trace instance CPU even if top command if removed from linux. I intend to dig into new relic's mechanism for retrieving metrics on linux since it doesn't provide source code. Thanks.

Comment: The general solution for this kind of problem is to run `strace -s 5000 -f -o /tmp/strace.out top` and then examine the /tmp/strace.out file to see what the command is reading.